# Magento 2 this is possible to set different SKU store wise on a same product

Tags: magento2, multistore, sku

I want to set different SKUs for different store wise. This is Possible?

Example,

I have an **ABC** Product.

> For the English Store, I want '**En-Abc**' SKU.
>
> For the Arabic Store, I want '**Ar-Abc**' SKU.

I have checked with store wise but SKU takes a Global Value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible and it should not be possible.

**Why is not possible:**
The sku is kept in the `catalog_product_entity` table. This is the main table for products. This means it's not an EAV attribute so it cannot have multiple values for the same product.
There is also an attribute called `sku` defined as `static`, but that one is there just for consistency. Even if you change the scope of this attribute it won't work.

**Why you skould not do it:**
SKU = Stock Keeping Unit.
SKU is a unique identifier for a product.
It should / does not depend on the language you are selling the product in. It should not really have meaning to the customer. Just for website owners.

**Conclusion:**
If you want different SKUs for different websites you will have to create different products and assign them only in the website / store view you want visible.

Comment: Hey @Marius, sorry to bring up an old topic, I am working for a globalized company that are using different SKU's for certain markets, the products are the same but carry different packaging. We've used separate products as you say above for some years and it's proving unmanagable (i.e. the catalog has 500 products but due to duplication is 2000 products long with the only visual difference being the SKU). The wrong products get applied to the wrong markets and edits are made on the wrong version ect.... I appreciate your comments but do you think "de-duping" our catalog is even possible?

Comment: @cygnusdigital. then why do you need the SKU to be different?

Comment: Because that's what the company require. I appreciate its not being used correctly! 
The company won't change all their business, warehouse systems & global SKU records of last 20 years to compliment their website. Example PRD012 is fine for European and UK stores, in China its PRD012 CN and Australia its PRD012 AU. The only difference is the product images and everything except SKU are translated as standard product attributes.
Currently we've 3 products for those 3 SKU's but we get admins looking for "Product Example" and find they edited PRD012CN by mistake!

Comment: sorry, I have no idea on what you can do.

Comment: No probs, thanks for looking at the post Marius!